# test meteor server side code with meteor-cucumber

Tags: testing, meteor, cucumberjs

I have successfully written features and the implementation of the steps for client side testing with [meteor-cucumber](https://github.com/xdissent/meteor-cucumber) but I can not figure out how to implement server code.

In the application there is a batch process which is started in `Meteor.startup` and runs every minute. It executes a function which must not be accessible from the client and hence there is no way to trigger it in a test case.

My question: how can I launch code in a feature implementation that will execute when `Meteor.isServer == true`?

Comment: Can you share your code in github repo ? I would love to learn how to do that.

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/xolvio/velocity?

Comment: Yes I'm using velocity

Comment: I have added a coder wall entry for this (but without server side test) https://coderwall.com/p/qj9d0w?i=9&p=1&q=author%3Adrgorb&t%5B%5D=drgorb